# Plotting a time series graph

Tags: python, pandas, math, plot, statistics

| Date | Country | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2017-12-29 | UK | 1 |
| 2017-12-28 | USA | 4 |
| 2016-12-27 | USA | 7 |
| 2016-12-26 | UK | 3 |
| 2015-12-25 | UK | 4 |
| 2016-12-24 | USA | 9 |
| 2015-12-23 | USA | 10 |
| 2014-12-22 | USA | 11 |
| 2014-12-21 | UK | 6 |

This is just a quick question as I am new to coding. How would I be able to plot these values on 2 separate time series plots so that I would be able to observe the trend of these values between the years 2015 and 2017? I need to have 2 separate graphs, one which will allow me to observe the UK trend and one which will allow me to observe the USA trend. I am using pandas in order to do this.

Any help is much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Hi epp2! matplotlib is a common plotting tool used with pandas: https://matplotlib.org

Answer (score 0):

You can use matplotlib in combination with pandas

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

df  = pd.DataFrame(
[
    ['2017-12-29','UK',1],
    ['2017-12-28','USA',4],
    ['2016-12-27','USA',7],
    ['2016-12-26','UK',3],
    ['2015-12-25','UK',4],
    ['2016-12-24','USA',9],
    ['2015-12-23','USA',10],
    ['2014-12-22','USA',11],
    ['2014-12-21','UK',6,]
],
columns=['Date','Country','Value'])

# gca stands for 'get current axis'
ax = plt.gca()

# make the string dates into date format
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%Y-%m-%d')

# for each country in your country column, plot a line on the axis, ax
for country in df['Country'].value_counts().index.values:
    df[df['Country']==country].plot(kind='line',x='Date',y='Value', ax=ax, label=country)
```

This is what it looks like when run in Jupyter
[image]